# Does using the action class of different module causes change in header during form submission?

Tags: forms, encoding, module, symfony1

I have problem with form submission to a action of different moudule, say e.g I have a module called "mymobile" from I am calling a action in module "register" which will process the registration, if there is any error in form I am setting the error messages and forwarding to "mymobile" module's page from where I called the action of "register", so it is modifying the header and my Japanese text is getting converted to some junk. Is there any way I can show error messages on my form without change of text? Any alternative for $this->forward() method? I am using symfony 1.1 and I tried $this->rediect() it will refresh the page.

Thank you in advnace

Comment: We need more info. What do you mean by « Japanese text is getting converted to some junk »? How do you « set the error messages »? Could you add some code examples?

Comment: @sglessard: Submitting a form from
mymodule/register to registermodule/confirm
If validation failed in registermodule we are forwarding to mymodule/register

Ex: $this->forward('mymodule','register');
 In this case page showing junk characters, Please give  me a solution for this. The Japanese text converting like this "èµ¤ããƒã‚¤ãƒ©ã‚¤ãƒˆã•ã‚ŒãŸãƒ¡ãƒƒã‚»ãƒ¼ã‚¸ã‚’å‚ç…§ã—ã€ã‚¨ãƒ©ãƒ¼éƒ¨åˆ†ã‚’ä¿®æ­£ã—ã¦ãã ã•ã„ã€‚"

Comment: Hard to understand what is going on without code example. In dev env, any error displayed on top of webpage (before <!DOCTYPE html>)?